# VS2019-Debugger produces high CPU (depending on CancellationTokens?)

Tags: c#, debugging, async-await, cpu-usage, cancellation-token

We're creating an application that contains a producer-consumer problem. There are more than 100 consumers who are notified of values. Each consumer runs in a `Task.Run` and is checking a `CancellationToken` to cancel it's work.

If this application runs in VS2019 (16.5.4 up-to-date) debugger it produces a high CPU usage. After detaching the debugger from a running application the CPU usage goes down to an expected value.

I was able to strip down the problem to this piece of code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press to start...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = cts.Token;

    var buffers = (from _ in Enumerable.Range(0, 40)
                   let queueLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1)
                   let queue = new ConcurrentQueue<object>()
                   select (queueLock, queue)).ToList();

    async Task Producer()
    {
        var instance = new object();

        var loop = 0;
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10, cancellationToken);
            foreach (var (queueLock, queue) in buffers)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(instance);
                queueLock.Release();
            }

            ++loop;
            if (loop % 100 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine(loop);
        }
    }

    async Task Consumer(SemaphoreSlim queueLock, ConcurrentQueue<object> queue)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await queueLock.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
            queue.TryDequeue(out _);
        }
    }

    foreach (var (queueLock, queue) in buffers)
    {
        Task.Run(() => Consumer(queueLock, queue), CancellationToken.None);
    }

    Task.Run(Producer, CancellationToken.None);

    Console.ReadKey();
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

The following picture shows the behaviour. The process is highlighted in task manager.

[image]

The funny part is that the problem lowers to arround half of the cpu usage if you change the line `var cancellationToken = cts.Token` to `var cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None`. The problem completely disappears if you substitute the `SemaphoreSlim` and `ConcurrentQueue<T>` to a `BlockingCollection<T>`. But this is not an option because this blocks all the threads in ThreadPool if no value is produced.

In our productive code we're using [`AsyncCollection<T>`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncCollection.cs) that causes the same problem. In that case we don't need a `SemaphoreSlim` but exclude this collection I used a `SemaphoreSlim` and `ConcurrentQueue<T>` to be sure that only natively provided types are used.

What couses this CPU usage?
How to avoid it?

Do I have to worry about that?

We tried to disable the diagnostics of VS but this doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

The code is compiled against .Net Framework 4.7.2 using VS 2019 (16.5.4).

**UPDATE**

After a hint of [Blindy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108796/blindy) I reported this issue to github roslyn:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44009

At the moment it is considered as a bug.

**++UPDATE**

[I tried Channels](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g9RE49) but the problem remains.

Comment: Depending on whether you'll get a response or not here, I recommend posting this as an issue on the Roslyn github. If you're right, this is either a compiler or a runtime (or a VS) bug.

Comment: Use the send feedback at the top left corner when this is happening and follow the instructions.

Comment: Have you tried using [`Channels`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Channels) as async queues? They are [praised](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) for their efficiency.

Comment: @Blindy Thx. I reported it and it is currently accepted as a bug.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias At the moment I haven't tried Channels but I will do this tomorrow (UTC+2). But I think the problem is a common one due to the usage of async locking. Maybe channels will be a good choice to use in our application but the problem of the debugger remains.

Comment: I don't want to give you false hopes. It is entirely possible that by using a `Channel` instead of `SemaphoreSlim`s you'll not notice any improvement. I just happen to know the selling point of the Channels, which is that they use highly efficient [`ValueTask`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/)s instead of `Task` objects internally for synchronization, and this sounds promising.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I updated the the question. Channels have the same problem.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Many thanks for the hint of Channels. I did a performance profiling of AsyncCollection vs. Channels. Channels are arround 55x faster than an AsyncCollection. From my point von view they're supporting all the features we need (unbounded and maxbound) and the code changes are minimal.

Comment: Bounded channels have the interesting option [`BoundedChannelFullMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.boundedchannelfullmode), that you'll not find in other implementations. There are also some other [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channeloptions) available, that may help at boosting the performance even more.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes I found the options and my profiling was using a guaranteed single writer and single reader because our application contains of exactly one reader task and exactly one writer task for each channel.